# NSCollectionView Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, uicollectionview, nscollectionview

I have an iOS app that uses a `UICollectionView`. I am now creating the app for Mac so I am trying to use `NSCollectionView` however I am not sure where I should start. 
I am trying to add the code below but it does not seem to be available. Where am I going wrong?
Thanks

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

return 30

}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ProjectsCellCollectionViewCell

cell.textLabel.text = "\(indexPath.section):\(indexPath.row)"

    return cell
}
```

Thanks.

I have followed the Quick Start Guide and I am stuck at this part:

```
-(void)insertObject:(PersonModel *)p inPersonModelArrayAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
[personModelArray insertObject:p atIndex:index];
}

-(void)removeObjectFromPersonModelArrayAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
[personModelArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}

-(void)setPersonModelArray:(NSMutableArray *)a {
personModelArray = a;
}

-(NSArray*)personModelArray {
return personModelArray;
}
```

I do not seem to be able to add these to my `ViewController.swift` file.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

iOS uses [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKit_Framework/) for UI elements, while Mac uses [AppKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/ObjC_classic/index.html). There are some big differences between these, mainly because iOS is for a mobile touch-based interface and Mac is for desktop keyboard/mouse interfaces. Shared between iOS and Mac is [Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/index.html). If there's an equivalent for Mac you can often replace `UI` with `NS` to find the class you're looking for. Your code won't work because there is no `UICollectionView` on Mac.

However, as you already seem to have noticed, there is [`NSCollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCollectionView_Class/), which Apple provide a [quick start guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/Introduction/Introduction.html) for.

Comment: I have followed the guide but I am stuck at the part above in the update.

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not seem to be able to add these..."? That code is Objective-C and is purely for the model side of the collection view. You can implement the model in any way you want.

Comment: I believe what Tom is getting at is the right way to do KVC with swift.  Clearly the objective-c code won't work with swift, but they key to the question is how to get a NSCollectionview working with swift.